# PHP - included file cant read variable

Tags: php, variables, include

I've included a file in my php script, but for some reason, it can't read a variable I've declared globally, because including the file...

**How I've arranged everything:**

The include is inside a function

The variable is declared globally (note: even when I declare the variable one line before the include, it can't read the variable (this *is* in a function though))

The included file reads the variable from a function (in other words: the statement `if ($errorcheckonly==true) {}` is inside a function in the included file)

Could any of this have an influence on why it's not working?

Code example:

```
Main file:
$errorcheckonly = true; //declared here or declared beneath, not both
function processOrder() {
$errorcheckonly = true;
include 'passengersform.php'; //forced to only use error checks
}
processOrder();

Included file:
function processtickets () {
echo '<script language="javascript">alert("'.$errorcheckonly.'");</script>';
if ($errorcheckonly==true) { exit; }
}
processtickets();
```

Comment: Please show your code. If it is long, try to create a minimal example that reproduces your problem. You might find the solution by yourself while creating this example... :-)

Comment: That is the reason why I described the layout. But like you asked, I added a piece of code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this other example

```
<?php
    $var = 'test' ;

    function A ( ) {
        global $var ;

        echo $var ;
    }   

    A ( ) ;
```

The output is `test`

Comment: I now have declared $errorcheckonly outside any function, used global $errorcheckonly; to read it in both the function in the main file as in the function in the included file, thanks!

Comment: Is it also possible to declare a global variable from a function, without declaring it outside that function?

Comment: Ah ok, too bad I can't do global variable = value; but I guess I can live with that, haha

Comment: THank you very much for your help once again!

Comment: Nopz .. the other way its store data in a session.

Answer (score 1):

See this simple example

```
<?php
function A ( ) {
    global $var ;
    $var = 'test' ;
}

A ( ) ;

function B ( ) {
    global $var ;
    echo $var ;
}   

B ( ) ;
```

Comment: Isn't a variable global by default when I declare it outside a function?

Comment: @laarsk No. Read the php docs for more on variable scope (http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: No, but either way, you'll have to use global $ var within the function that will define the scope for you

Comment: Wow. This is an eye opener for me. Really because I've done similar things before, and it always worked perfect for me...
Also, would I have to use global to read the variable? Now that's weird. (However, very handy aswell, as you can now have duplicate variables?)